# JPA java rollback doesn´t work when I generate an exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, transactions, rollback

I have a problem with the rollback of a transaction,
Im trying to do a rollback after a validation by sending an exception, but it is not being executed´.

This is my class:

```
@Service
public class ReiniciarContraseniaServiceImpl implements ReiniciarContraseniaService {

    /** Identificador en la tabla parametro para la contraseña generica */
    private static final long IDENTIFICADOR_CONTRASENIA_GENERICA = 1;
    
    @Autowired
    ParametroRepository parametroRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public ReponseContrasenia actualizarContraseniaGenerica(String nuevaContrasenia) throws Exception {

        ReponseContrasenia respuesta = new ReponseContrasenia();

        //1.- Encriptamos la contraseña generica
        String contraseniaGenericaEncriptada = EncriptaUtils.encrypt(nuevaContrasenia);

        //2.- Actualizamos con el parámetro que nos llega
        int numeroRegistrosActualizados = parametroRepository.actualizarValorParametroPorId(contraseniaGenericaEncriptada, IDENTIFICADOR_CONTRASENIA_GENERICA);

        //3.- Validamos si se actualizo correctamente
        if (numeroRegistrosActualizados == 1) {
            //Si no se actualizo 1 registro mandamos excepción para generar un rolback
            throw new Exception("Error no se actualizo el valor, numeroRegistrosActualizados: " + numeroRegistrosActualizados);
        }
        
        //4.- Agregamos mensaje de éxito
        respuesta.setMensaje("Éxito al actualizar la contraseña genérica");
        respuesta.setEstatusActualizacion(ReponseContrasenia.ACTUALIZACION_CORRECTA);
        
        return respuesta;
    }

}
```

This is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ParametroRepository extends JpaRepository<Parametro, Long> {

    /**
     * Método para actualizar el campo valor de la tabla parametro por su id
     * 
     * @param valor, es el dato que se actualizara
     * @param idParametro, es el dato del where
     * @return int, número de filas actualizadas
     */
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Parametro p SET p.valor = :valor WHERE p.idParametro = :idParametro")
    int actualizarValorParametroPorId(@Param("valor") String valor ,@Param("idParametro") Long idParametro);
}
```

This is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/contrasenia")
public class ReiniciarContraseniaController {

    @Autowired
    ReiniciarContraseniaService reiniciarContraseniaService;

    @PutMapping("/actualizaContraseniaGenerica")
    public ResponseEntity<ReponseContrasenia> actualizaContraseniaGenerica(@RequestBody RequestContrasenia contrasenia) {

        ReponseContrasenia respuesta = new ReponseContrasenia();
        
        try {

            respuesta = reiniciarContraseniaService.actualizarContraseniaGenerica(contrasenia.getContraseniaGenericaNueva());
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            respuesta.setEstatusActualizacion(ReponseContrasenia.ACTUALIZACION_INCORRECTA);
            respuesta.setMensaje("Error inesperado al intentar actualizar la contraseña generica, revisar logs del back");
        }
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(respuesta, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I execute the actualizarContraseniaGenerica method and despite sending the exception it does not make any rollback, the updated value remains. My database is Mysql, Im using spring-boot 3.2.0

Already tried with:

- @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
- @Transactional( rollbackFor = Exception.class)
- TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
- ALTER TABLE parametro ENGINE = INNODB; (in my data base)
- spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine = innodb

Nothing works